# How to get object type after retrieving it as document from mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, bson

I am developing a nodejs app with multiple kinds of users, for example "user" and "page". I am using MongoDB to save my data, and passportjs for authentication. I need to provide different serialization methods according to user type. Sample code:

```
    passport.serializeUser((obj, done) => {
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            console.log("serialising user", obj);
            done(null, { id: obj._id, type: 'user' });
        } else if (obj instanceof Page) {
            console.log("serialising page", obj);
            done(null, { id: obj._id, type: 'page' });
        } 
    });
```

The problem here is that `instanceof` does not work with documents retrieved from MongoDB. They were created using the constructors of User/Page, but now I can't differentiate between them, since they are now both of type object. How should I deal with this?

Comment: Why no use a field on the database, userType, and save the values "User" or "Page" and then just check that field from the doc?

Comment: The documents are already in different collections, so I don't need to differentiate between them in any other context. I think this might be a solution, but I would not prefer it for redundancy. Having 10,000 users in the collection of users all with the type "user" does not seem as the best solution out there.

Comment: @Ismail K. Wahdan find a unique field from these two different collections and based on the field and field value apply this logic

Comment: @kavigun yes, another choice and more simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find a unique field from these two different collections and based on the field and field value apply this logic

Comment: @Ismail K. Wahdan accepts as an answer if that resolves your query and close the question.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that all different fields in them can be optional at certain times, so for example a field like page.creationDate can be undefined because it hasn't been defined yet, or because it is actually a user.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is indeed using a field `obj.userType ='user'/'page'` in the returned objects, but it I did not save it in the database. Instead I query the object, get the document BSON back, and then simply add the field to it. This way I don't have to save it to all users all of the times, it's just their for the retrieved user object needed for the session until it terminates.